# Laravel: How to add a word for a language in RUNTIME

Tags: php, laravel, localization

Well the title is pretty clear.

I want my USERS to add custom lines in Laravel. Obviously they should not go open `messages.php` file and edit it :')

Imagine that user wants to create a category. But they want to name that category in several languages.

Can I do this in Laravel? if not what's the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you need is for your Category model to be translatable and you want it to have multiple translations.

A common way of solving this is by moving the data you want translated out to its own table; and then having a reference to the model that the translations belongs too.

---

The following package: [Laravel Translatable](https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable) explains it very well and has a couple of very nice examples.

**Below I changed the migration example to fit your needs.** It should give you a general idea of how to solve this.

```
Schema::create('category', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('category_translations', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('locale')->index();

    $table->unique(['category_id','locale']);
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

---

Additionally you can find a very good article by [Freek Van der Herten](https://github.com/freekmurze) that explains [How to add multilingual support to eloquent](https://laravel-news.com/2015/09/how-to-add-multilingual-support-to-eloquent/)

Comment: So is there any way to use Laravel's default localization?

Comment: Not if you want users to be able to handle the editing.  Unless you make some super custom solution to edit the files and interpret them to display nicely for the users.

Comment: This Laravel Translatable uses database to store translations which is a huge performance issue while Laravel uses PHP array which is fast enough.. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: This is not a performance issue. Heck, reading and writing from disk files for translations is a considerable larger performance issue. Regardless, these files are only meant for system text and not translation of user content by design.